# What is the best tool for creating and managing RSS feeds?

Tags: rss

My boss just asked me to maintain and create an RSS feed of hot news topics in our field for our site.

Are there any easy way to use tools for managing an RSS feed, where I can easily go in and add/edit entries?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you could probably do is sign yourself for a [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com) account if you do not mind this being public (as it will mean no extra work needed) or download and setup [Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.org) on a local machine.

Whilst these are blogging tools, they will allow you to easily publish and manage articles  and will automatically generate the RSS feed for you.

Comment: (WordPress, not Wordpress.)

Answer (score 1):

At work, we use [Delicious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicious_%28website%29) to share interesting stories. You can add news stories to your account, tag them, and comment on them.. People can then access the RSS feed of this account. For adding new stories, you get a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) in the browser. Editing existing entries is easy as well, either go to the Delicious webpage or just add the web page again via the bookmarklet, you'll get a dialog to edit the entry.

[Google Reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Reader) has a nice feature as well, you can share a story from an RSS feed. I am unsure however how I would share an arbitrary story, one that I didn't read in one of my feeds.

Answer (score 0):

If your company use [SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint), then you can use SharePoint to create a page of RSS feeds and you can control who has access.